# Creating a Custom Array Size with Random Numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a function that returns an array of a custom size and is populated with random numbers. My whole code is as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int check_error(int a);
void initialize_array(int array[],int a);
void print_array(int array[],int a);
int replace(int array[],int i, int b, int c);

int main(void) 
{
    int asize, array;
    printf("Hello!\nPlease enter the size of the array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &asize);
    check_error(asize);
    while (check_error(asize)==0)
    {
            printf("Invalid input! Enter the size of the imput size again:\n");
            scanf("%d", &asize);
    }
            if (check_error(asize)==1)
    {
            initialize_array(array, asize);
    }
}

int check_error(int a)
{

    if (a> 0 &&  a <= 100)
            return 1;
    else
            return 0;
}
void initialize_array(int array[], int a)
{
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i < a; i++)
    {
            array[i]=rand()%10;
    }
}
```

Specifically I need help getting `initialize_array` to work as intended.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is your code doing? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: My question is how do I create this array with random numbers. This code is taking a integer value from the user and which defines how big the array is. The code checks to see if the array size is between 0 and 100 then either a 0 or 1. I need the program to create an array that is "asize" big with random numbers from 0-9 to fill those spots in a 1D array.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, remove your previous definition of array and then do this:

```
if (check_error(asize)==1) {
        int array[asize];
        initialize_array(array, asize);
        // other stuff here
}
```

Note that array is only valid between the { }'s of the if(check_error) statement.

Comment: +1 the only other way to really do this without dynamic allocation is using a VLA on the caller-side, and keeping the exiting implementation of `initialize_array()`. Also, adding the (admittedly overkill) functionality of providing a lower and upper bound for the range of random numbers generated as a pair of parameters would be a nice touch. +1 regardless. This is a viable solution.

Comment: The lab states that i cannot use pointers in my code have to use functions and pass the arrays through the functions.

Comment: Ok, whole new answer based on WhozCraig's suggestion. No pointers.